# Can't open Outlook (Office 365) on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, office365

Every time I open Outlook, I receive the error:

> Cannot start Microsoft Outlook. Cannot open the Outlook window. The
>   set of folders cannot be opened. An unexpected error has occurred.

After trying to run Outlook in safe mode, and as Admin (which didn't solve the problem), I tried seeing if the problem was related to a corrupted `.pst`/`.ost` or a corrupted navigation pane:

1. I used Outlook's Inbox Repair Tool [`ScanPST.exe`] to diagnose/repair any corruption within the Outlook data files, running it on every Outlook data file [image: screenshot]
2. To rule out Navigation Pane corruption, I ran `outlook.exe /resetnavpane`

Neither of these resolved the problem, so I ran an Offline, then Online, repair of Office but the problem persisted, so I reinstalled Office and am still getting the same error.

- Could this be an issue of conflict due to access credentials since I have OneDrive configured?
- How can I resolve this issue without formatting the computer?

Comment: Make sure your PST files are backed up, and make sure you know how to make your email accounts.  Now, go to Control Panel, Mail and then Profiles, and Delete your Outlook Profile(s).   Restart the computer and see if Outlook opens. It will want to create a new account, so cancel that and create a new account manually using the email tool in Control Panel.

Comment: I would reinstall Office 365 based on that error

Comment: @John thanks a lot. That solved my issue and everything happened as you wrote (consider posting as the answer). For the future, I will start using the Mail section in the Control Panel to add new accounts/profiles.

Comment: @Ramhound Doing an online repair of Office is, for all intents and purposes, a reinstallation

Comment: @Ramhound I have reinstalled the Office and the error still persisted as you may read in the third paragraph of the question counting from the bottom. Apart from that, what JW0914 said may also apply.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 The issue is with one of your `.pst` or `.ost` files, **not** Outlook - did you use `scanpst` to scan the `archive.pst` _and_ default `outlook.pst`?  If so, close Outlook > Backup the `.pst` files by renaming them _(delete the `.ost` files, as they'll be auto-rebuilt upon a Send/Receive since they're just a mirror of the email server)_ > Remove **all** data files, including the default `outlook.pst` > Open Outlook >  Re-create the default `outlook.pst` _(if the issue still exists, close Outlook again and also delete the Outlook profile from `Control Panel` > Mail [setup])_

Comment: @JW0914 I have only used it in the email files that appeared in the directory where I had all the Outlook Data files that were linked with the emails I had configured. I only had one profile.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 Please follow the rest of the steps then, as the error you're receiving is a database error referring to a set of folders contained within one of the `.pst` files _(there's a slim chance it could be an `.ost` file, but highly unlikely, as these are a secondary mirrors of the email server - i.e. they're not a primary database like a `.pst`)_.

Comment: @JW0914 I can't confirm if that will work, as John's suggestion solved my problem. But I suggest adding as an answer to the question, as it may help other solve the issue.

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 It's the exact same information... I was typing that as the notification popped up that an answer had been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your PST files are backed up, and make sure you know how to make your email accounts.

Now, go to Control Panel, Mail and then Profiles, and Delete your Outlook Profile(s). Restart the computer and see if Outlook opens.

It will want to create a new account, so cancel that and create a new account manually using the email tool in Control Panel.

Comment: @JW0914 on the last sentence, John is referring to the constraint/requirement that I have established for solving the issue (check the last paragraph of the question).

Comment: I changed the answer to delete the reference but it was in response to the original question. It is not really needed for a complete answer, so I deleted the reference.

Comment: _(I deleted my previous comment since the statement was removed)_ @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄 I read your question in its entirety and not only is formatting and reinstalling Windows not a resolution to the problem, the exact same issue would have presented itself after a reinstall upon opening Outlook, as the issue is with one of the Outlook database files, not Windows.

Comment: Thanks for all your sharing.